# Не работает autoreconf в Debian 8

Tags: debian

Не работает комманда 'autoreconf -i' в Debian 8 x64. Выдаёт ошибку:

**autoreconf: 'configure.ac' or 'configure.in' is required**

Как исправить?

Comment: 1. отстутствуют оба указанных файла. 2. чего вы хотите добиться с помощью этой команды?

Comment: Нужно скомпилировать кое-что при помощи команд ./configure и make.  Для этого нужен autoreconf

Comment: *Для этого нужен autoreconf* — судя по приведённой вами же информации, нужно что-то совершенно другое. посмотрите в документации по сборке: readme, install или что-то подобное. если не найдёте, приложите к вопросу список файлов/каталогов в том каталоге, где вы хотели бы выполнить программу `make`.